# How do I run objcgen directly to do .NET Embedding on MacOS

Tags: ios, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I followed the instructions  at [Installing .NET Embedding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/get-started/install/install) and...

1. I installed Visual Studio 2019 on my Mac 10.14.6
2. I created a Xamarin.ios class lib project
3. I installed Nuget Embeddinator-4000
4. I added a hello world function: void main(){ Console.WriteLine("hello world");}...
5. I built without problem.
6. The next instruction says to.....

> ```
>  Running manually  
>     Now that the NuGet is installed, you can run the tooling by hand.          
>     Open a Terminal (macOS) or Command Prompt (Windows)
>     Change directory to your solution root
>     The tooling is installed in:
>     ./packages/Embeddinator-4000.[VERSION]/tools/objcgen (Objective-C)
>     ./packages/Embeddinator-4000.[VERSION]/tools/Embeddinator-4000.exe
>     On macOS, objcgen can be run directly.
> ```

...But there is no ./packages/ directory  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
> Last login: Fri Mar  6 10:05:48 on ttys002
> DOUGs-MacBook-Pro:Embedding_2020-03-06 dbell$ ls -l total 24
> -rw-r--r--  1 dbell  staff  2193 Mar  6 09:02 Embedding_2020-03-06.csproj
> -rw-r--r--  1 dbell  staff   827 Mar  6 08:58 Embedding_2020-03-06.sln
> -rw-r--r--  1 dbell  staff   249 Mar  6 09:03 HelloWorld.cs drwxr-xr-x  3 dbell  staff    96 Mar  6 08:58 Properties drwxr-xr-x  3 dbell 
> staff    96 Mar  6 08:58 bin drwxr-xr-x  8 dbell  staff   256 Mar  6
> 09:03 obj DOUGs-MacBook-Pro:Embedding_2020-03-06 dbell$ ls ./packages
> ls: ./packages: No such file or directory    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
> DOUGs-MacBook-Pro:Embedding_2020-03-06 dbell$
```

Comment: check in your bin or obj folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, hah!  The objcgen tools need to first be built.  I found instructions how at Github > Embeddinator-4000 > README.md > "Building".

Summary -- installation of .NET to Objective-C converter...

```
1.  Clone github > Embeddinator-4000
git clone https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000.git
2.  cd into the cloned dir
3.  Install other stuff:
git submodule update --recursive --init
4.  Build the .NET to Objective-C converter:
cd objcgen
make
5.  Build the 'wrapper' (ie. command access) to objcgen (took 10-15 minutes for me):
make nuget
6.  Generate Objective-C from your .NET C# class lib
7.  <somewhere in the bowels of your Mac>/Embeddinator-4000/objcgen/_build/objcgen     <elsewhere in the bowels of your Mac>/hello-from-csharp/hello-from-csharp/bin/Debug/hello_from_csharp.dll --target=framework --platform=iOS --outdir=output -c --debug
```

NOTE:  hello-from-csharp is from [MICROSOFT DOC .NET EMBEDDING HELLO WORLD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/get-started/objective-c/ios)